# Screen shoot quality worse than normal

Tags: c#, winforms, screenshot

I am trying to capture a part of my screen.
The problem is even if I use png to save the image the quality still worse than if I would just use normal print screen.

Here is the code I use:

```
        //display a save file dialog for the user to set the file name
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();

        saveFileDialog.Filter = "PNG (*.png)|*.png";
        saveFileDialog.FilterIndex = 0;
        saveFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

        //if the user proceed saving the picture
        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //simplify code with constant numbers for demo

            //get the width of the panel we need the screenshoot off
            int x = 10;
            //get the height of the panel we need the screenshoot off
            int y = 10;
            //create the ractangle of the screenshoot panel
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 5, 5);
            //create new bitmap
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

            //get the screenshoot of the panel
            g.CopyFromScreen(rect.Left, rect.Top, 0, 0, bmp.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

            string fileName = saveFileDialog.FileName;
            if (!fileName.Contains(".png"))
                fileName += ".png";

            bmp.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Png);
        }
```

EDIT:

Example image form what I take with code:
[image]

Normal screenshot:

[image]

It does not look so different here, but it is worst.

Comment: It doesn't help but I think it is a bad idea to use PNG for this anyway... most of the time you'll end up with a bigger file than jpg would

Comment: Are you able to provide us with some example images?

Comment: @Bartdude Yeah I know png is bigger than jpg but I dont really care in this situation. I prefer quality.

Comment: it looks like it's being scaled down, which is causing the fuzziness.

Comment: @DLeh I was zooming in and out of the images, the code taken image was always worst, probably I just cropped out a part of the code taken image when it was a bit zoomed out.

Comment: @LarsTech As I mention in my code (comment) I used fix number to simplify the calculation of the panel location and width

Comment: also @Daniel, the term is "screenshot" not "screenshoot"

Comment: @Bartdude - Nothing wrong with png if you want to retain quality.  Even at the best settings, jpg throws out data (and thus clarity) of an image...it doesn't appear that it's a document that's pages and pages long.  The amount of space saved would likely be relatively trivial.

Comment: Have you tried changing the ImageFormat to something besides PNG to see if the problem still happens (jpg or bmp)?  If it doesn't, then the problem is in how the framework creates the PNG

Comment: @Bartdude : The last time I measured, screenshots in png were in fact __smaller__ that those in jpg; and of course nice and crisp as opposed to the mushy jpg fonts

Comment: PNG is perfect for this type of things. Your code seems to be OK, [here is a screenshot I took with it](http://i.imgur.com/z3uuyT5.png), copy pasted from your post on a new winform application.

Comment: Please see the comment on the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The top image in your question was rescaled, smaller than the original.  This is noticeable in images that contain fine detail, like the ClearType anti-aliasing pixels used to make the text more readable.  When they get rescaled, the visual effect is ruined and text looks a lot worse.

It is entirely unclear *why* the image was rescaled, nothing in your code could cause that.  Double-check by using the debugger to inspect the bmp.HorizontalResolution property, it should match the DPI of your video adapter.  Simplest explanation that it was done by whatever image viewing program you used, perhaps to make the image fit the window.  Try zooming out.

Comment: Yeah you guys are right, the code takes perfect screenshot. I opened the image in windows photo viewer(default); it resized the image and made it look worst. Opened the image in GIMP and it displayed perfectly. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to use a external library I suggest you **FMUtils.Screenshot**. Its available as a NuGet-package.

I just tried it and the quality is like the standard screenshot from windows. Here's a shortexample:

```
new ComposedScreenshot(new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100)).ComposedScreenshotImage.Save(@"PATH_TO_FILE\example-screenshot.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

The pixel format you use only uses 8 bits each for the different color channels. You could try using PixelFormat64bppARGB to get 16 bits per color.

Resource on the PixelFormat enumeration: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Based on the screenshots, this is clearly not a bit depth problem. Also, almost every computer screen uses only 8 bits per channel so going to 16 bit is just a waste of space.

Comment: Unfortunately that something what would not work, but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @EtienneMaheu The screenshots weren't up when I posted this answer.